# I have daily data. How can I restrict the ticks to just the months?

Tags: python, datetime, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataframe with one column of one year of daily dates and two columns of data. I'm creating a heatmap of the data, using the dates as the y-axis. How can I limit the y-axis ticks to just the months? I'm ok with 'January' appearing either at the row representing the 1st of the month, or at the row representing the middle of the month. For scalability purposes, the 'Date' column will always be chronological and will always have constant increments, though not necessarily exactly 1 day as in my example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[dt.date(2019,1,1) + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(365)],
               'a':[x%5 for x in range(365)], 'b':[x%3 for x in range(365)]})
print(df.head())
         Date  a  b
0  2019-01-01  0  0
1  2019-01-02  1  1
2  2019-01-03  2  2
3  2019-01-04  3  0
4  2019-01-05  4  1
```

1) Standard heatmap code. This results in a cluttered y-axis.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df[['a','b']], yticklabels=df['Date'])
```

[image]

2) Using MonthLocator from matplotlib.dates (as 'mdates'). I couldn't get this to work. This results in no y-axis labels.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df[['a','b']], yticklabels=df['Date'])
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
```

[image]

3) Using fancy math. This can't account for months having unequal numbers of days.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df[['a','b']])
ax.set_yticks(range(0,df.shape[0]-1,df.shape[0]//12)) #13 evenly spaced tick marks
ax.set_yticklabels(df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%B %d %Y')).iloc[range(0,df.shape[0]-1,df.shape[0]//12)]) #Select dates matching tick marks
```

[image]

4) No example code here. I tried locating dates where the 'day' was 1. This wasn't a problem. I just couldn't figure out how to create properly unevenly spaced ticks to assign them to.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the only clean solution here is to use matplotlib and format the axis. To this end convert the dates to numbers and set the extent of the image to the range of date values. (To be precise, one would can also add half a day, such that the day is in the middle of each pixel). This assumes that dates (and hence pixels) are equally spaced.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[dt.date(2019,1,1) + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(365)],
               'a':[x%5 for x in range(365)], 'b':[x%3 for x in range(365)]})


x = np.arange(len(df.columns[1:]))
y = mdates.date2num(df['Date'].values)
z = df[["a", "b"]].values

dy = y[1]-y[0]
extent = [-0.5, len(x)-0.5, y[0]-dy, y[-1]+dy]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(z, aspect="auto", extent=extent)
ax.yaxis_date()
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set(xticks=x, xticklabels=df.columns[1:])
fig.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now you can also use matplotlib dates locators and formatters without problem

Comment: As I understand it, this is basically taking my seaborn heatmap and getting relatively the same output using matplotlib's imshow, setting me up for my 4th approach. I tried it out (thanks for the copy-and-pastable code) and added the locator and formatter lines, and it looks good. It's kind of amusing, since originally I was using imshow, but switched to heatmap because I didn't like using a nested for loop to create my (r,c,n) array from an (r,c) dataframe (it was actually my previous stackoverflow question).